# C# Regex remove line

Tags: c#, regex, hl7

I need to apply a regex in C#.
The string looks like the following:

```
MSH|^~\&|OAZIS||C2M||20110310222404||ADT^A08|00226682|P|2.3||||||ASCII
EVN|A08
PD1
PV1|1|test
```

And what I want to do is delete all the lines that only contain 3 characters (with no delimiters '|'). So in this case, the 'PD1' line (3rd line) has to be deleted.
Is this possible with a regex?

Thx

Comment: You probably should use an HL7 parser like [NHapi](http://nhapi.sourceforge.net/home.php) for this kind of work.

Answer (score 1):

The following will do what you want without regular expressions.

```
String inputString;
String resultingString = "";
for(var line in inputString.Split(new String[]{"\n"})) {
    if (line.Trim().Length > 3 || line.Contains("|"))
        resultingString += line + "\n";
}
```

This assumes that you have your file as one large string.  And it gives you another string with the necessary lines removed.

(Or you could do it with the file directly:

```
string[] goodLines = 
    // read all of the lines of the file
    File.ReadLines("fileLocation").
        // filter out the ones you want
        Where(line => line.Trim().Length > 3 || line.Contains("|")).ToArray();
```

You end up with a String[] with all of the correct lines in your file.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `StringBuilder` instead of `string` here?

Comment: @Alex, anytime you are building up strings in a loop, you should most definitely use a `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation.  However, this is just a simple example to illustrate the logic involved.

Comment: A regex solution is much simpler and more concise. Why would you suggest otherwise?

Comment: @Josh, because there is more than one way to solve the problem.  This code is very simple to read.  Adding a Regex adds complexity.  I'm not saying a regex is bad.  It is just not the only way to do it.

Comment: @jjnguy - This is an obvious case for a Regex and the author asked if a Regex was possible.  Also, I believe this is harder to read than a Regex and more complex.

Comment: @skaz, I would argue that using a regex is overkill in this situation.  But, I really don't care.  Either way would be fine in my code.  Heck, I may have even used a regex if I were in the mood at the time.

Answer (score 1):

This:
`(?<![|])[^\n]{4}\n`
Regex matched what you wanted in the online regex tester I used, however I believe that the `{4}` should actually be a `{3}`, so try switching them if it doesn't work for you.

EDIT:

This also works: `\n[^|\n]{3}\n` and is probably closer to what you are looking for.

EDIT 2:

The number is brackets is definitely `{3}`, tested it at home.

Answer (score 0):

why not just get a handle to the file, make a temporary output file, and run through the lines one by one. If there is a line with 3 characters, just skip it. If the file can be held in memory entirely, then maybe use the GetLines() (i think that's what the method is called) to get an array of strings that represents the file line by line.

Comment: File.ReadAllLines  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This regex will identify the lines that meet your exclusion criteria `^[^|]{3}$` then it's just a matter of iterating over all lines (with data) and checking which ones meet exclusion criteria. Like this for instance.

```
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(data, @"^.+$")
{
  if (!Regex.IsMatch(match.Value, @"^[^|]{3}$"))
  {
     // Do Something with legitamate match.value like write line to target file.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the three characters always going to be by themselves on a line?  If so, you can use beginning of string/end of string markers.

Here's a Regex that matches three characters that are by themselves on a string:

```
\A.{3}\z
```

\A is the start of the string.
\z is the end of the string.
. is any character, {3} with 3 occurrences

Answer (score 0):

^ - start of line.
\w - word character
{3} - repreated exactly 3 times
$ - end of line

```
^\w{3}$
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the case where a line has 3 chars and one of them is a pipe delimiter.

Comment: \w does NOT include the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Just a general observation from the solutions I've seen posted so far.  The original question included the comment "delete all the lines that *only* contain 3 characters" [my emphasis].  I'm not sure if you meant literally "only 3 characters", but in case you did, you may want to change the logic of the proposed solutions from things like

```
   if (line.Trim().Length > 3 ...)
```

to

```
   if (line.Trim().Length != 3 ...)
```

...just in case lines with 2 characters are indeed valid, for example.  (Same idea for the proposed regex solutions.)

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague.

As stated, the answer is something like this

`(?:^|(?<=\n))[^\n|]{3}(?:\n|$)` which allows whitespace in the match.
So `"#\t)"` will also be deleted.

To limit the characters to visual (non-whitespace), you could use
`(?:^|(?<=\n))[^\s|]{3}(?:\n|$)`
which doesent allow whitespace.

For both the context is a single string, replacement is '' and global.
Example context in perl: `s/(?:^|(?<=\n))[^\n|]{3}(?:\n|$)//g`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
        text, 
        @"^[^|]{3}(?:\r\n|[\r\n]|$)", 
        "", 
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it Using Regex

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$", "");
```

[a-zA-Z0-9] will match any character or number
{3} will match exact number of 3